# Change C++ display text with HTML txt file?

Tags: html, c++

I want to be able to change C++ display text from an HTML txt file,  is this possible to do?

Comment: Have you done research on that error? It's a very common mistake, and means exactly what it says. Note: `.` refers to the root window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is your using pack and grid. pack and grid do the same thing but grid lets you choose where to put it. you can only use one or the other in a canvas. also you had hello and goodbye in the same spot on grid(). heres your fixed code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

label = None


def change1():
    global label
    label.config(text="Hello World!")


def change2():
    global label
    label.config(text="Goodbye World!")


def main():
    global label
    rootWindow = Tk()

    label = ttk.Label(rootWindow, text="Hello World!")
    label.grid(row=0, column=0)

    button1 = ttk.Button(rootWindow, text="Hello!", command=change1)
    button1.grid(row=0, column=1)

    button2 = ttk.Button(rootWindow, text="Bye!", command=change2)
    button2.grid(row=0, column=2)

    rootWindow.mainloop()


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are using both .grid() and .pack() the difference is that in .grid you can choose where to put your button or whatever while in .pack() it places it automatically. this is why I will recommend you to use the .grid() option.